# Current date in Google BigQuery in filter condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using below filter in my BigQuery

```
sales_date >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

I am getting below error

```
No matching signature for operator >= for argument types:
TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signatures: ANY >= ANY
```

I am new to BigQuery. Not able to figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

you should use

```
DATE(sales_date) >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are comparing a `TIMESTAMP` and a `DATE`, the error message is telling you that both need to be of the same type, so you need to convert `sales_date` into a date field before making the comparison, something like `EXTRACT(DATE FROM data_timestamp)` should do it, making your query:

```
EXTRACT(DATE FROM sales_date) >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for your data.